# update balance into database [logic help]

Tags: web3js

If a user deposit money to his Ethereum address that is generated for user after signup.

So how to get amount transferred by the user to update that amount into database field?

I'm using web3 with full node

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running an archiving full node, you may use this RPC interface against your full node: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance. If you're not running an archive node, you'll only get balances back to the most recent X (250?) blocks.

I've seen looseness in the words people use to describe the various ways of running a node. Some people call a `full node` what I would call a `non-archiving tracing node.`  Using parity, a `non-archiving tracing node` is started with `parity --tracing on`.

In order to get historic balances (i.e. prior to X (250?) blocks ago), you must run an `archive` node with this command:

```
parity --tracing on --pruning archive
```

(Tracing is probably optional here, but adds little extra disc space usage compared to the archive.)

There's an equivalent command for `geth` but I don't know what it is.

Comment: `web3.eth.getBalance ` with this command can we only get the balance? How can we track transactions? web3.eth.getBalance

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to track incoming ether transfers in Ethereum, especially those performed by smart contracts.  That's why I would recommend tracking outgoing transfers rather than incoming.  Here is the scenario:

1. User signs up
2. Back-end generates unique deposit address to the user (user knows the address, but only back-end known corresponding private key)
3. User transfers some ether to his deposit address
4. Back-end periodically checks balance of user deposit addresses
5. Back-end notices that balance of some deposit address is greater than certain threshold
6. Back-end initiates ether transfer from deposit address to cold storage
7. Back-end tracks status of transaction published at step 6
8. Once ether is successfully moved form deposit address to cold storage, back-end updates user balance in database